# How to add products with images

Tags: php, image, magento, frontend, product

I am not able to add products on my Magento with images.

The products are added successfully when the image is not uploaded.

Still the images are shown in the back end , but we click on the add product button it showing some error like this.

> Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\favis\vendor\magento\framework\Config\Dom.php on line
>   273

How to remove this error? Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: in query you have not passed any parameter?

Comment: i didn't change anything in the dom.php.